# Send traces directly from python application to Grafana Cloud's tempo instance without Grafana agent

Tags: python-3.x, grafana, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, grafana-tempo

Here is python script that sends test trace directly to tempo instance :

```
import base64
from typing import Tuple

from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.http.trace_exporter import \
    OTLPSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import Tracer, TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor

def create_span_exporter_for_tempo() -> Tuple[Tracer, BatchSpanProcessor]:

    resource = Resource(attributes={"service.name": constants.APP_NAME})

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Basic {base64.b64encode(f'{constants.GRAFANA_USERNAME}:{constants.GRAFANA_PASSWORD}'.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')}"
    }
    tempo_exporter = OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint=constants.TEMPO_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)

    trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider(resource=resource))
    tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
    span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(tempo_exporter)

    trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(span_processor)
    return tracer, span_processor

tracer, span_processor = create_span_exporter_for_tempo()
with tracer.start_as_current_span("test") as span:
        print("test!")
        span.set_attribute("check", "works")
```

My Grafana Cloud setup looks like this :
[image]

Here are some of variations of tempo endpoint tried :

```
1. https://tempo-prod-04-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net/tempo
2. https://tempo-prod-04-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net/tempo/v1/traces
3. https://tempo-prod-04-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net/v1/traces
4. https://tempo-prod-04-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net:443/tempo/v1/traces
5. https://tempo-prod-04-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net/tempo/v1/trace
```

All of these endpoint return the same output :

`Failed to export batch code: 404, reason: 404 page not found`

[image]

Please note that, I have tested out this tempo instance by setting up [grafana agent](https://github.com/grafana/agent) & I was able to send traces via grafana agent.

My requirement is to send traces without deploying grafana agent as I am sending traces from lambda & do not want to run agent somewhere else 24X7.

Here is python library being [used](https://pypi.org/project/opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-http/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use OTLP Gateway. Make note of the following values that you’ll need in order to write OLTP:

- OTLP Endpoint URL: `https://otlp-gateway-<zone>.grafana.net/otlp` (ex: `https://otlp-gateway-prod-us-central-0.grafana.net/otlp`).
- Basic Auth Username: `<instanceID from Grafana details page>`
- Basic Auth Password: `<Grafana API Key>`

Doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/data-configuration/otlp/send-data-otlp/

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this: If you want to send traces directly from the code as in the example above, append `/v1/traces` to the endpoint mentioned above, so `https://otlp-gateway-<zone>.grafana.net/otlp/v1/traces` (see https://community.grafana.com/t/opentelemetry-endpoint-of-grafana-cloud/85359/5)

Comment: @jan-garaj, @moertel :
Now this is not working. I have been trying to send traces to instance setup using new grafana cloud account and it keeps giving me `authentication error: invalid authentication credentials`.
URL I am using is : 
`https://otlp-gateway-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net/otlp/v1/traces`

I tried cloud policy token as well as api key both.
Any idea if something has been changed ?

Comment: @UtsavChokshi `authentication error: invalid authentication credentials` is not a problem with URL, but with used credentials. You have wrong authentication, e.g. wrong `Basic Auth Username` and/or `Basic Auth Password`. Only you have access to your credentials/org, so only you can find what is wrong.

Comment: @JanGaraj
That's the problem. The code I have put it in question work for one grafana instance and does not work with another one. I have checked my credentials so many times. 
It is correct. I thought maybe the way auth works at grafana has changed with new instances.

Comment: @UtsavChokshi that OTLP gateway doesn't have SLA. But you can still complain to your Grafana cloud support.

Comment: @UtsavChokshi it's hard to tell what might be giving you the credentials error. I can at least confirm that the process as such is working for me. Things to check are whether your "prod-us-east-0" is indeed the right location and whether you accidentally included a newline `\n` in your base64 encoded credentials.

For future reference, if anyone wants working Python code: https://gist.github.com/moertel/32ed043d77268d17c28c4c285136bff9